# rails3: how do you join subsets of large tables, since joins/associations don't seem to support it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm running Rails 3.0.0.

I want to be able to parameterize conditions in joins. This is important
for performance.

From what I can tell, there's no easy way to do this directly with joins().
All joins() takes is a list (in various forms) of associations. However,
associations do take conditions. So, the question is how do I parameterize
an association's condition.

```
    class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
            belongs_to :bar

            belongs_to :special_bar,
              :class_name => "Bar", :foreign_key => :bar_id,
              :conditions => { :special => 77 }     # need this condition to be a parameter
    end

    class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
            has_many :foo
    end
```

This allows me to:

```
    Foo.joins( :special_bar )
```

Which will result in SQL like:

```
    ...
    INNER JOIN bars
      ON bars.id = foo.bar_id
      AND bars.special = 77 -- need to be able to control this condition
```

I did notice the association condition is limited to the class being joined
to, and that the 'where-style' all text option is not supported. Instead,
the "symbol => value" grammar is the only supported form.

However, this is exactly what I want, except I need to be able to
parameterize '77' so I can pass the value in. Better yet, I'd like to be
able to pass in 'where style' grammar for the condition.

Yes, I know that the following works, but it doesn't work generally,
and I need a general solution. Specifically, this fails if I need to join
another table after the "AND special = 77".

```
    Foo.joins( :bar, "AND special = 77" )
```

And moving the condition to to a where clause is insane because pairing
down a huge join is insane. The right thing to do is prevent the huge
join in the first place by placing limits on the values going into the join.

And no, sub-queries really don't work either. I need to be able to order
the result.

I find it hard to believe there isn't a way in ActiveRecord to join small
subsets (conditionally selected) of two huge tables, and order the result.

Yes, I've googled and searched stackoverflow. The rails guides won't go
anywhere near a topic like this. Discussions around the topic joins tend
to be very vague and very simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo

  cattr_accessor :special_val

  belongs_to :special_bar,
             ...
             :conditions => proc { "special = #{self.class.special_val}" }


end
```

Untested, but I think it will work, although it's not pretty.

```
Foo.special_val = 20
Foo.special_bar
```

I hope this helps.